# Ways to implement a recurring functionality?

Tags: c#

I'd like to implement a recurring functionality to do something that activates, say, every Monday.

What are the ways of doing this programmatically in a Window Forms application that runs continuously in a server?

I'm familiar with delays but I haven't implemented delays that span for a week or month.

Comment: I think we'd need more details, but you could write something that performs said functionality, and then schedule it to run with Windows task scheduler as per specification.

Comment: please do not use a winforms app on a server. Use a service or a scheduled batch. that way you do not need to log in.

Comment: As mentioned, if your going to do something which requires a day to day check of something - don't even think of doing `File > New > Windows Form` - you should consider a windows service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion your best bet is to write this functionality in a Console app and create a task on the server using Scheduled Tasks (or SQL Scheduler, or your favorite Scheduling tool) to execute it at whatever interval you need.

I don't like to see apps have "hidden" tasks in the code that execute at a specific time.  Too many opportunities to fail without notification.

With a scheduling tool you can view/change the schedule without having to touch source code.

As side notes, Windows Forms apps should run on the *client*, not on the *server*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're app is already running anyways,  what I would do is have a periodic task that checks whether you want to do your weekly task

here's psudocode to demonstrate the logic.

```
if(today is Monday && i didn't do this task yet today)
{
    //do monday stuff
}
```

Comment: This would probably work, but wouldn't it require that said program be running 24/7, even though it only runs (possibly once) on Mondays?  Seems like too much overhead/room to break unnoticed.

Comment: @turbo, well the op did ask for a solution `"in a Window Forms application that runs continuously in a server"`

Comment: Are there any reliability issues with delays(6 days)?

Comment: Hmm, actually thinking about it, for this code to work, wouldn't it have to be a in a loop that is constantly running or be called with delays?  I think my conjectures might still be something to worry about.

Comment: @Mikk my solution doesn't advocate a 6-day delay, instead you do shorter, as short as 10 minute delays, and then check the `DateTime` and potentially other state vairables to determine whether or not you want to run the task

Comment: rather than a busy wait you should be performing a blocking wait.  Determine the amount of time between now and when you need to do something else, and then sleep for that amount of time.

Comment: @turbo  Yes, It would have to be part of a periodic task, although not quite 6 days

Comment: mind you, If the whole purpose of your project is to do this weekly task, I would probably investigate the scheduled task/windows service route

Comment: I see, I think @Mikk needs to give more details about what is trying to be done/if this is part of a bigger project, etc.  The best recommendation seems dependent on this information.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should perform this operation under windows scheduled task.  It will then take care of the recoccurrance as well as timing.

If you need to do this via a winforms application, then there are two options - periodic time polling or blocking wait/sleep.

With periodic time polling, you set a time interval in which the application must run.  Then in a loop check if this period has elapsed, and take action.  You can set the required level of accuracy in side the loop.

With blocking wait, you sleep the running thread until it is time to execute.  The only issue with this approach is if the server restarts, the application **should** regain it's state and resume any sleep operations.  The accuracy of this approach should be within a few seconds (depending on the time drift of your server).